# Conversion from milliseconds to Unix Timestamp from different times gives same result

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, epoch

I have two variables:

`tempTimeRequests`
`timeLastUpdateRequests`

Both are given in milliseconds since epoch.

I'm facing a bizarre behaviour from js:

the result I get for

```
alert(
    tempTimeRequests+"\n"+
    timeLastUpdateRequests+"\n"+
    Date(tempTimeRequests)+"\n"+
    Date(timeLastUpdateRequests)
)
```

is

```
1369063665000
1369063651000
Mon May 20 2013 17:27:51 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Mon May 20 2013 17:27:51 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

How come I have the same value of seconds if clearly have 51 seconds for the second (which gives the right result) but 65 (which would give 05 seconds) for the first ?
I am really freaking out with that.

Comment: That's weird. When I print them separately (using `console.log` each), I get the correct values. When I combine them into one `console.log` call, they show the same value (obviously the same for `alert`)

Comment: If you use `new Date(`, it seems to work for me

Comment: From MDN: "calling it as a regular function (i.e. without the `new`operator) will return a string rather than a `Date` object;". So that seems to be perfectly fine. Also from ES5: http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling the `Date` constructor as a function returns the **current** date.

From the [specification](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.2)

> **15.9.2 The Date Constructor Called as a Function**
>
> When Date is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it returns a String representing the **current time (UTC)**.
>
> **NOTE** The function call `Date(…)` is **not** equivalent to the object creation expression `new Date(…)` with the same arguments.

This is unlike when using [`new Date`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.4.2) which does what you expect.

Comment: Great explanation.  Thanks, I tried finding this when I gave my answer.

Comment: @Robbert It's not me, it's the language specification :) A lot of active effort is being made to make the ECMAScript language specification more readable and accessible. http://es5.github.com also throws in easy navigation and links to resources like MDN.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

This should fix the problem

```
alert(
  tempTimeRequests+"\n"+
  timeLastUpdateRequests+"\n"+
  new Date(tempTimeRequests)+"\n"+
  new Date(timeLastUpdateRequests) 
)
```

Comment: OK, but that doesn't explain why calling `Date()` alone exposes this kind of behaviour. Is it a bug?

Comment: I'm not sure why it does that, other than the fact that Date is an object and to create an object, you use the new keyword.  The way you were calling it was using it as a function, which maybe some browsers support but others don't.

Comment: I would guess it does that because when the Javascript runs it evaluates the `Date(time)` functions first assigning it to the first time first then the second time, then when constructing the string to `alert` it gets the `Date` object as a string which would at that time be set to the second time.